# How can I remove or hide the stocks app from Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, stocks.app

I'd like to hide the icon of the stocks app so it doesn't appear in the collection of circles. Apple's documentation says you can't do this, but I hope someone finds a back door or way to minimize it past the normal icon size.

> “You can’t hide the apps that came with Apple Watch.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “Apple Watch User Guide.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/4HEW6.l

If I could make the icon totally black, or hide it or shrink it or better, have it uninstalled and not take any space would be ideal.

Apple Watch app runs on iOS 8.3 and Watch OS 1.0.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can delete the stocks app from your phone on iOS 10 - and that removes it from the watch. There isn't a way to have it on the phone but not on the watch.

There were currently no workarounds, jailbreaks or non-obvious ways hide and minimize the stocks app on the Apple Watch apps display on iOS 9 and associated watch OS. The rest of this answer applies if you cannot upgrade to iOS 10 and watchOS 3.

Consider making a long tail arrangement of apps placing the ones you don't want to see to the end of the line.

[image: tadpole arrangement with bad apps at the tail]

In practice, you'll see the few apps centered around the clock face central point of the graph.

p.s. still can’t remove the stocks app on watchOS 7.1 - the beatings will continue until morale improves.

Comment: Lol it's so much Apple way.

Comment: @Ultra Yah - it's 1.0 so I understand cutting functionality and iterating. We'll see in time if they insist this app is crucial to the watch experience or let users personalize this aspect of the experience.

Comment: This is a good workaround and I am amazed by the oversight of this by apple. It's like we've gone back to iPhone 1 days :)

Comment: Great answer! Given the limitations mentioned above. Thanks!